# python3 django manage.py runserver error

Tags: django, python-3.x, authentication, cloud9

I have a project in AWS cloud9.
I tried to login via LinkedIn or Facebook, I use django.
When I run the command: `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080` I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 307, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ec2-user/environment/gowith/django_social_project/django_social_project/settings.py", line 17, in <module>
    from config import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/config.py", line 733
    except Exception, e:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in `except Exception, e:` be cause in python 3, you should write `except (Exception, e):`

If you use an external package, ensure it is Python3 compatible, or use python 2.7 yourself otherwise.